# Connecting Doctrine in Symfony 3 to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony

I'm used Ruby on Rails and Django before for web app development. I'm now learning Symfony and trying to create entities. I've already done the database configuration and have successfully created a MySQL database using Doctrine in the command line.

I then followed all the steps as described in the [Symfony book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).

However, when I run `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Product`, I got the following error message in the terminal:

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
>   [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping" in class AppBundle\Entity\Product does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

I googled around. On [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1402), it seems like I need to use the Doctrine Common 3.0.x branch. I am not sure how to do that and also not sure whether this answer is the right solution for me or not.

I'm using Symfony 3.0.1, PHP 5.5.30 and Mac OS X 10.11.3.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please post your entity code

Comment: it's exactly the same entity code as on http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy without code because we can't know which example you tried.
I've see your error sometimes and usually appear because the

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

Is missing. Please, paste your code.

Comment: There is only one "product" example in the link I've provided. I did have the line you've mentioned in my code. Anyway, I've solved this weird error by using the command "php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity" to automatically generate all the entities and their getters and setters. Thanks a lot!